# Inputstream/Movie image quality toggle live wallpaper

Tags: java, android, inputstream, live-wallpaper, movie

Hi there I'm making a live wallpaper and I want to have an option so that people can disable it being hd (so that low power devices will also be able to use my app). My live wallpaper uses an inputstream and a Movie. Is there anyway I can downscale the quality using code?

The reason I am using movie is because I am using an animated gif for my wallpaper.

(Or do you have to edit the quality of the Canvas that the live wallpaper draws onto the movie each frame?)